# How do I get the count for each item using v-for in Vue?

Tags: javascript, oop, vue.js

I have this Vue code:

```
var itembox = new Vue({
    el: '#itembox',
    data: {
        items: {
            cookiesncreme: {
                name: "Cookies N Cream",
                description: "description"
            },
            chocolateswirl: {
                name: "Chocolate Swirl",
                description: "description"
            },
            peanutbutter: {
                name: "Peanut Butter",
                description: "description"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And this HTML code:

```
<div id="itembox">
    <div v-for="(item, index) in items">{{ index }} - "{{ item.name }}"</div>
</div>
```

**I am trying to output the code in a numbered list, for example:**

```
<div>1 - Cookies N Creme</div>
<div>2 - Chocolate Swirl</div>
<div>3 - Peanut Butter</div>
```

**But since my items have keys already, it comes out like this:**

```
<div>cookiesncreme - Cookies N Creme</div>
<div>chocolateswirl - Chocolate Swirl</div>
<div>peanutbutter - Peanut Butter</div>
```

Is there any other way to get a number count for each item? Thanks!!

Comment: If you want to create a numbered list, would it work in your case to just use `<ol>` instead of `<div>`?

Comment: Its more complicated than that, I just tried to simplify it for the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Vue.js, there's actually a third parameter that you can pass in this case. For example, you could do this:

```
<div id="itembox">
    <div v-for="(item, index, i) in items">{{ i+1 }} - {{ index }} - "{{ item.name }}"</div>
</div>
```

Notice how I used the `i` parameter, which is actually the index number. I've created a working Fiddle of this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ecofic/eqyou9uv/). If you would like to learn more about Vue.js, I hope you'll checkout my [Vue.js training course](https://www.ecofic.com/courses/vue-getting-started). If this answer helped, I hope you'll mark it as such and vote this item up.

Comment: Broken fiddle :-(

Answer (score 1):

Accourding to the documentation [Vue API: v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-for)

> Alternatively, you can also specify an alias for the index (or the key if used on an Object):
>
> ```
> <div v-for="(item, index) in items"></div>
> <div v-for="(val, key) in object"></div>
> <div v-for="(val, key, index) in object"></div>
> ```